# Make Xcode 9 Console auto scroll to bottom

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode9

My questions is about Xcode 9 IDE.

For some unknown reason, soon after a debug session is started, Console stops auto scrolling to bottom. It stops somewhere in the middle (see screenshot below).

Is there a way to fix this annoying behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try putting the scrollbar all the way to the bottom before you begin debugging... sometimes it will autoscroll based on whether or not it's all the way down (works this way in Console.app).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Click in the console pane.

Step 2- Hit 'fn' + "→"   (The 'End' shortcut on macOS)